# Debugging a PHP function that henders Holiday list to open

Tags: php, debugging, web

I am working as a trainee in a software company and given a task in which I have to check why the holiday list is not open? I have found that the problem is with this php function but unable to find the error in the code

```
public static function API_getYearHolidays($year = false) {  //API
    if ($year == false) {
        $year = date('Y', time());
    }
    $q = "SELECT * FROM holidays";
    $runQuery = self::DBrunQuery($q);
    $rows = self::DBfetchRows($runQuery);
    $list = array();

    if ($year == false) {
        $list = $rows;
    } else {
        foreach ($rows as $pp) {
            $h_date = $pp['date'];
            $h_year = date('Y', strtotime($h_date));
            if ($h_year == $year) {
                $list[] = $pp;
            }
        }
    }

    if (sizeof($list) > 0) {
        foreach ($list as $key => $v) {
            $list[$key]['month'] = date('F', strtotime($v['date']));
            $list[$key]['dayOfWeek'] = date('l', strtotime($v['date']));
        }
    }


    $r_error = 0;
    $return = array();
    $return['error'] = $r_error;
    $r_data['message'] = "";
    $r_data['holidays'] = $list;
    $return['data'] = $r_data;

    return $return;
}
```

Error at Console:

> Some error found in requestHolidayList action
>    TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
>       at holidayList$ (http://dev.hr.excellencetechnologies.in/hr/main.aea75426f6f0d3ea338b.js:152712:26)
>       at tryCatch (http://dev.hr.excellencetechnologies.in/hr/main.aea75426f6f0d3ea338b.js:222594:40)
>       at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (http://dev.hr.excellencetechnologies.in/hr/main.aea75426f6f0d3ea338b.js:222828:22)
>       at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (http://dev.hr.excellencetechnologies.in/hr/main.aea75426f6f0d3ea338b.js:222646:21)
>       at next (http://dev.hr.excellencetechnologies.in/hr/main.aea75426f6f0d3ea338b.js:121393:27)
>       at currCb (http://dev.hr.excellencetechnologies.in/hr/main.aea75426f6f0d3ea338b.js:121469:7)
>       at 
>   holidayList$ @ index.js:17

Comment: Have you tried to run the code? What is the expected output, list any errors if you are getting.

Comment: Whats henders mean, if you meant hinders whats that mean? Whats not working?

Comment: addded the error in question

Answer (score 0):

Change 
    **return $return;**  to 
    **return json_encode($return);**  if you are using JSON.parse() at client side.

If you directly return array/NULL and try to parse it it causes SyntaxError for JSON.parse().

Comment: not working. got new error in console: Fetch failed loading: POST "http://dev.hr.excellencetechnologies.in/hr/attendance/API_HR/api.php".

Comment: $return is encoded in json in another file in which it is referred to. I think the problem is with this $r_data['message'] = ""; is it?

Comment: No, $r_data['message'] = ""; will not create a problem.

Comment: Share your client side script which handling the resonse

Comment: everything is working properly. Problem is "API_getYearHolidays() function is not returning any value to the _api.php_ from where it is being called."